# How to return an error from node.js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, exception, error-handling

I have a Node.js API that calls a function that does some DB query. There are try-catch blocks. In case of success, this function returns an array with two values. If there is some error the flow goes to the catch block. I want to return the error to the API calling it and it should directly go to the catch block of API but it's not doing as such. How should the variable receiving the function handle the error?

```
app.post("/someApi", async (req, res) => {
 try {
    let getDetailsRes = await getDetails(Id);
    let var1 = getOrderDetailsRes[0];
    let var2 = getDetailsRes[1];
   //Do something with var1 and var2
  return res.status(200).send({ "Success" }); 
 }
 catch (e) {
  return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage: "Internal Server Error" + e.message });
 }
```

The function is as follows:

```
async function getDetails(Id) {
   let client = await pool.connect();
     try {
       checkUpgradeQueryRes = await client.query(
      `
        SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = $1
      `,
    [Id]
    );
    throw new Error("some Error");
   } catch (e) {
    client.release();
    console.error(`Error occured during DB query: ${e}`);
    return new Error(`Error occured during DB query: ${e}`);
  }
    client.release();
    console.log("Success");
    return [true,new Date()];
}
```

Here, when an error is thrown the flow goes to the catch block which returns an error but the variable getDetailsRes receives it and in the next line tries to extract its 0th and 1st index value. How to return an error such that when the variable getDetailsRes receives it. It directly goes to the catch block of the API.

I tried:

```
if(getDetailsRes instanceof Error){
      return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage:"Error Occured " + getDetailsRes.message });
  }
```

Is this a good practice?

Comment: You can `Throw` a new error and catch it in some middleware instead of sending a response . Docs of common frameworks: [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) - [Koa](https://koajs.com/#error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried two things

```
   if (getOrderDetailsRes.name && getOrderDetailsRes.name==='Error') {
      client.release();
      return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage: "Error Occured " + getOrderDetailsRes.message });
    }
    if (getOrderDetailsRes instanceof Error) {
      client.release();
      return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage: "Error Occured " + getOrderDetailsRes.message });
    }
```

Both of them will work but are considered bad practices. The issue I faced was `getDetailsRes` was treating the error as a normal response. So, we can do:

`return Promise.reject(new Error("Error occurred during DB query"));`
and make the function where it was called a traditional promise with`.then()` and `.catch()` block.
Ref: [Link](https://thecodebarbarian.com/async-await-error-handling-in-javascript.html#:%7E:text=Using%20catch()%20on%20the%20Function%20Call&text=Remember%20that%20async%20functions%20always,returned%20promise%20will%20reject%20too)